# Tool to perform MULTIPLE regex replacements on text

Tags: software-recommendation, text-editor

It's often been the case that I've wanted to a) perform *a series of* regex replacements on some text in a specific order, and b) *save this* replacement to use for later. However, despite the purported usefulness of such a tool, I have not found a program, convenient shell script, or online utility which allows a user to do this.

I will list a number of programs and utilities that I have tried:

1. Sublime Text: this works well, but only one regex replacement can be made at a time, which is rudimentary for my purposes.
2. [Regex101](https://regex101.com): This is an extremely invaluable tool for regex replacements, but it also doesn't support multiple substitutions.
3. [Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/155939): This is probably the best way to perform a series of replacements and save it as well for later. However, it is incredibly cumbersome to use, doesn't show a preview of the replacements that are being made, and has some really ugly syntax.

Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do from the command line, from a program, or from an online website?

Comment: When I need to make multiple edits to a text file using **regex** I use `sed` as it supports multiple _editing commands_, and they are done in the order they are laid out. I have one `sed` _command_ I run every day that has 14 _editing commands_ strung together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in BBEdit using something called a "Text Factory".

A text factory (File => New => Text Factory) allows you to string together as many transformations (including Replace All, but there are many others) as you like.

Once you've set it up, you can apply it as a Text Filter to the active document (or selection range), or to a specific file, or folder, or multiple files/folders.

Answer (score 0):

BBEdit, LibreOffice, and similar tools allow regular expressions in their search/replace dialogues

Typically, there is a check box to allow regex or plain text.  Then you can replace one at a time or click "replace all."

Comment: I apologize, I may not have explained my question clearly enough. I'm looking to perform a series of different regex replacements easily, not carry out all instances of a replacement (which most text editors can do)

Comment: Hmm.  Well, if a preview of each replacement is necessary, you might have a difficult search.  I've never considered it unwieldy to put a series of `s:old:new:g;` in a file and feed it to perl.  `perl -p -i -e "$(cat file)" *` to run it on all the files in a directory.

Comment: You could make a backup of the 'before' files, then use `sdiff` to look for changes you don't like.

Comment: I see; a preview isn't *that* big of a deal, but it would be helpful. I just thought there would definitely be something like this, but maybe using perl is the best way—I thought it was kind of awkward to use

Comment: This answer could be simplified. ***bbedit***

Comment: How is bbedit different from Sublime Text? From what I can see, it only allows one replacement at a time

Comment: @SkeletonBow You have mentioned two amazing tools. ST uses language and the idea of unix pipes as a superpower. [BBEdit uses text factories](https://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/benefitsexercise.html) which is an entirely different interface and idiom also as a super power. Both can accomplish amazing feats, but they have to support your understanding of how to assemble logic to automate. Neither is wrong or right, just different in their respective power. They are _very_ different in implementation, not in result once harnessed and used fully.

Comment: Wow, that's interesting. Looks like it can do what I'm searching for, and it can also replace across files.. that's a feature I've wanted in the past! Thanks!